# css top nav - left nav (menu), title in center, right side (more buttons) - howto?

Tags: css, menu, title, navbar

I want to have a top nav that looks something like this:
div = [] , space = .

[[menu-icon][logo]....[page title].....[some-icon][some-icon]]

so the menu and logo area stick to the left.
the page title in the middle.
2 more icons that stick to the right.

I tried a couple of ways but none worked for me.
My best solution had everything in place but then the links/icons were not clickable, the text was "over" them.

appreciate any help.

Here's my plunker of it:
http://plnkr.co/edit/CBnH6Ewa4QJTu5FBC2Mi

======EDIT=====
thanks to @Mark Simpson , i fixed a typo in the css and have the title bar centered and links clickable by using z-index:-1 on the centerpiece.
but I'd the title like it to be clickable too.
I use this on some pages.
Any suggestions on how to solve this with css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.navbar .center {
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.navbar .right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

See: http://plnkr.co/edit/1XLrK4Iuq6CPSYmGPDYn?p=preview

Comment: Ty that works perfectly. Is there also a solution in case I want the center area to be clickable too? with this solution it's "behind" the div and cannot be clicked.

Comment: @samz Yup. I've updated my answer. Give it an explicit width that's narrow enough to not cause it to cover the icons.

Comment: @mark_simspon : the last suggestion puts the title in the center but then the icons on the right drop a line :(

Comment: @samz Sorry, I've updated my answer again. Please accept the answer as correct if it works.